# How to catch id and token from url in Angular 7+

Tags: angular, angular-router

**Question was updated**
I was looking for information on the Internet but unfortunately I did not find anything. There is a lot of information about how Angular can catch values from the urlstring if you transmit them as a parameters, but I have another case.

After succsessfully regsitration submittng, my app sends url from backend to frontend. This url contains `id` and `token` and looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/activate?id=MzU&token=541-b257b0475444facd4e3f
```

My question, how can I in Angular 7+ catch the `id` and `token` values from url?

**Pls note**, as I said this url comes from back end. After user registration, my backend generates this url and sends email which contains it. User clicks the url and opens it in the browser.

Thanks!

Currently I tried following, none of this works:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'activate*', component: EmailConfirmationComponent },
  // otherwise redirect to root
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

---

```
// email-confirmation-component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

export class EmailConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {
  private id: string;
  private token: string;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.token = params['token'];
      console.log(this.id, +'\n' + this.token);
    });

    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });

    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']);
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['token']);
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params['token']);
      console.log(params['id']);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That `url` is gnarly. Y_Moshe's approach is the best way, you really should adjust the backend and send those things in as queryParams. However, if you just cannot adjust it at all, you will have to set up a special route like `path: 'activate/:id/:token'`. Use a couple resolvers to parse the id and token values and resolve them, making them available in your route snapshot in your `EmailConfirmationComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the answers came up to me. After a long search, I finally found the right solution by trying different solutions. Actually there was very easy way to get the required parameters from URL. There was an important thing missing by me. We can/must  use `;` semicolons instead of `&` and `?` have a look at the last part of *"Navigating back to the list component"*, official [angular dokumentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component).  And create the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/activate;id=MzU;token=541-b257b0475444facd4e3f
```

In this way angular will catch them as a URL values.

So, my final approach was this:

```
//app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/guards/auth.guard';
import { EmailConfirmationComponent } from './auth/register/email_confirmation/email-confirmation.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'activate', component: EmailConfirmationComponent },
  // otherwise redirect to root
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Note** you don't have to pass any `:id`'s or `:token`'s directly to your `Routes` configuration.

---

```
//email-confirmation.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/shared/services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-confirmation',
  templateUrl: './email-confirmation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-confirmation.component.scss']
})
export class EmailConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    // redirect to home if already logged in
    if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });
  }
}
```

So, here we make just common subscribtion to Observable of `ActivatedRoute.params` and `console.log(params)` them

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong:

```
http://localhost:4200/activate/id=MTk/token=540-6293a45d6567def9ea3b
```

it cannot be like this because then u don't have a route for this URL, should be like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/activate?id=MTk&token=540-6293a45d6567def9ea3b
```

and then just get them from

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams...
```

Comment: As I said I can't configure the url in another way. I tried it, but then my backend sends completely wrong url

Comment: well then the problem is in the backend fix it there, why would be any problem with this url ? there is one more option that i see u can do something like this maybe? http://localhost:4200/activate/ID?token=540-6293a45d6567def9ea3b

Comment: if this url can work well with ur backend, then u can do it with angular

Comment: Your approach does not work, I've invested so much time to get the string like you said but the application does not catch the params from the url. Note this is comes from backend, angular does not have any idea about this params. In your example it means that angular takes all values after `?` question mark as params but this is not true.

Comment: check new answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this URL the routes configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'activate*', component: EmailConfirmationComponent },
  { path: 'activate/:id', component: LoadSomeComponent},
  // otherwise redirect to root
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

then on init of 'LoadSomeComponent' u should get the ID from params and token from queryParams.

btw will better to add this route as a child of 'activate' route.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be easier to have your back end send those two parameters in a JSON string (which would be way easier to parse).  Otherwise you could treat the URL like any other string and use TS string commands like .indexof to pull the information out.

Comment: No unfortunately I can't, because this url will be sent to an user email, not directly to my app. This means user have to klick this url in he's email client which will open it in the browser